# Is $E[X_sX_t^2]=0 \,\,s<t$ for a MDS?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, martingales, filtrations

Let $(X_t,\mathcal F_t)$ be a stationary martingale difference sequence (MDS). Can we say that
$$E[X_sX_t^2]=0 \quad s<t \quad ?$$

For $s>t$ we can use the the law of iterated expectations and the pull-out property.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true in general.

One example would be to take $Y_n \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 2)$ and $Z_n \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ independent with
$$
X_0
= \begin{cases}
Y_0 & \text{w.p. }1/2,\\
Z_0 & \text{w.p. }1/2,
\end{cases}
\quad
X_{n+1}
= \begin{cases}
Y_{n+1} & \text{if } X_n \geq 0, \\
Z_{n+1} & \text{if } X_n < 0,
\end{cases}
$$
and the natural filtration $\mathcal{F}_n = \sigma(X_0, \dotsc, X_n)$.

But now, we have that, since $Y_{n+1}$ and $Z_{n+1}$ are independent of $X_n$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E} X_n X_{n+1}^2
&= \mathbf{E}[Y_{n+1}^2 X_n; X_n \geq 0] + \mathbf{E}[Z_{n+1}^2 X_n; X_n < 0] \\
&= \mathbf{E} Y_{n+1}^2 \mathbf{E}[X_n; X_n \geq 0] + \mathbf{E} Z_{n+1}^2 \mathbf{E}[X_n; X_n < 0] \\
&= (\mathbf{E} Y_{n+1}^2 - \mathbf{E} Z_{n+1}^2) \mathbf{E}[X_n; X_n \geq 0] + \mathbf{E} Z_{n+1}^2 \mathbf{E} X_n \\
&= \mathbf{E}[X_n; X_n \geq 0] \\
&> 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you. In in the last equality you used $E[X_n]=0$ which can be shown using the law of iterated expectation and pull out property right? Also is $X_n$ stationary?

Comment: Each $X_n$ is distributed as a mixture of a $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ and $\mathcal{N}(0, 2)$ random variable. Also, the recurrence is the same regardless of the starting point of the sequence. Together, this shows that $(X_n)$ is stationary. Moreover, you can see directly that the mean of this distribution is zero (the mean of any mixture of mean-$0$ random variables has mean $0$).